# Selecting a particular iframe in a web console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I am running some javascript which just does some dom selections and change the value of things. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I think this is because the page has multiple iframes and it will depend on which iframe is "loaded" if the scripts will work in the console.

My question is how do I check which iFrame the console is referencing and how do I change it?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Console knows document and window. Anything else is defined by you. What selectors do you use?

Comment: Sometimes this works: document.querySelector('input[title="Title"]').value = "test"; and sometimes it doesn't.  Looks like it depends on what part of the page has focus.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ Every iframe gets its own document object. So I guess you have to be in the correct iframe.  But how do I do that?